# TypeError: abis.filter is not a function

Tags: web3js, react, abi

I've been working on a React program that provides a frontend for a Solidity smart contract I'd been making. The `App.js` code is shown below:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Web3 from 'web3';
import RightsTokenABI from './RightsToken.json';

function App() {
  // Set the contract address
  const rightsTokenAddress = '0xAddress'; // Replace with the actual contract address
  const rightsTokenABI = RightsTokenABI; // Import the RightsToken contract ABI

  const [web3, setWeb3] = useState(null);
  const [rightsTokenContract, setRightsTokenContract] = useState(null);
  const [account, setAccount] = useState('');
  const [rtBalance, setRtBalance] = useState(0);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  // Initialize Web3 and the RightsToken contract
  useEffect(() => {
    async function initializeWeb3() {
      // Check if MetaMask is installed
      if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
        const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
        setWeb3(web3);

        // Request account access
        await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });

        // Get the user's account
        const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
        setAccount(accounts[0]);

        // Initialize the RightsToken contract
        const rightsTokenContract = new web3.eth.Contract(rightsTokenABI, rightsTokenAddress);
        setRightsTokenContract(rightsTokenContract);

        // Get the user's RT balance
        const rtBalance = await rightsTokenContract.methods.balanceOf(accounts[0]).call();
        setRtBalance(rtBalance);
      } else {
        setMessage('MetaMask is not installed. Please install MetaMask and connect to an Ethereum network.');
      }
    }

    initializeWeb3();
  }, [rightsTokenABI]);

  // Function to request RT from the faucet
  const requestRT = async () => {
    try {
      // Request RT from the faucet contract
      await rightsTokenContract.methods.distributeRT().send({ from: account });

      // Update the RT balance
      const rtBalance = await rightsTokenContract.methods.balanceOf(account).call();
      setRtBalance(rtBalance);

      setMessage('Successfully received RT from the faucet.');
    } catch (error) {
      setMessage(`Transaction failed. Error: ${error.message}`);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>RightsToken Faucet</h1>
      <p>Request RT from the faucet:</p>
      <p>Account: {account}</p>
      <p>RT Balance: {rtBalance}</p>
      <button onClick={requestRT}>Request RT</button>
      <p>{message}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I ran `npm start`, though, an error was shown once my Metamask wallet was connected:

```
abis.filter is not a function
TypeError: abis.filter is not a function
    at ContractBuilder._parseAndSetJsonInterface (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:70611:31)
    at new Contract (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:70316:10)
    at new ContractBuilder (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:86321:11)
    at initializeWeb3 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:59:37)
```

Online, I looked into any `abis.filter` function, but never saw any reference to it. I also went through my `App.js` code and the smart contract I was running, but there was no mention of it. My ABI- `RightsToken.json`- is located in the same folder as the `App.js` code, and was correctly formed after the smart contract was compiled. Web3 is installed, version web3@4.1.2. How should the error be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the issue lay in the fact that I wasn't directly referencing solely the ABI part of `RightsToken.json`, but rather the entire JSON file. I specified that it was to import only the ABI:

```js
const rightsTokenABI = RightsTokenABI.abi; // add ".abi" to RightsTokenABI
```

And that error disappeared.