# RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert\n at EIP1559FeeMarketTransaction.fillFromResult

Tags: solidity, truffle, react

I've been working on a smart contract in Solidity, the code shown below:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract RightsToken is IERC20, ERC20Burnable, Ownable {
    // A mapping to track each user's RT balance
    mapping(address => uint256) private _rtBalances;

    // A mapping to track each user's voting power
    mapping(address => uint256) private _votingPower;

    // The total available RT for distribution
    uint256 private _totalAvailableRT;

    // List of addresses that have received RT
    address[] private _users;

    // Events
    event RTDistribution(address indexed user, uint256 amount);

    constructor(uint256 initialSupply) ERC20("RightsToken", "RT") {
        _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply * 10**uint256(decimals()));
        _totalAvailableRT = initialSupply * 10**uint256(decimals());
        /*if (msg.sender == owner()) {
            transferOwnership(msg.sender); // Set the contract owner to msg.sender
        }*/
    }

    // Function to distribute RT to users daily from the faucet
    function distributeRT() external payable {
        //require(_totalAvailableRT > 0, "No RT available for distribution.");

        // Calculate the amount of RT to distribute to each user
        uint256 dailyDistribution = _totalAvailableRT / (_users.length);

        // Update the user's RT balance and voting power
        _rtBalances[msg.sender] += dailyDistribution;
        _votingPower[msg.sender] += dailyDistribution;

        // Reduce the total available RT
        _totalAvailableRT -= dailyDistribution;

        // Transfer the RT to the user
        _mint(msg.sender, dailyDistribution);

        // Add the user to the list if they haven't received RT before
        if (_rtBalances[msg.sender] == dailyDistribution) {
            _users.push(msg.sender);
        }

        emit RTDistribution(msg.sender, dailyDistribution);
    }

    // Faucet function to allow anyone to request RT
    function faucet() external {
        //require(_totalAvailableRT > 0, "No RT available in the faucet.");

        // Calculate the amount of RT to distribute
        uint256 faucetAmount = 1 * 10**uint256(decimals()); // 1 RT

        // Ensure the user hasn't received RT from the faucet today
        //require(_rtBalances[msg.sender] == 0, "You already received RT from the faucet today.");

        // Update the user's RT balance and voting power
        _rtBalances[msg.sender] += faucetAmount;
        _votingPower[msg.sender] += faucetAmount;

        // Reduce the total available RT
        _totalAvailableRT -= faucetAmount;

        // Transfer the RT to the user
        _mint(msg.sender, faucetAmount);

        // Add the user to the list if they haven't received RT before
        if (_rtBalances[msg.sender] == faucetAmount) {
            _users.push(msg.sender);
        }

        emit RTDistribution(msg.sender, faucetAmount);
    }

    // Function to transfer RT to another address
    function transferRT(address recipient, uint256 amount) public {
        //require(recipient != address(0), "Invalid recipient address.");
        //require(_rtBalances[msg.sender] >= amount, "Insufficient RT balance.");

        _rtBalances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        _rtBalances[recipient] += amount;

        emit Transfer(msg.sender, recipient, amount); // Emit ERC20 transfer event
    }

    // Function to get a user's RT balance
    function rtBalanceOf(address user) external view returns (uint256) {
        return _rtBalances[user];
    }

    // Function to get a user's voting power
    function votingPowerOf(address user) external view returns (uint256) {
        return _votingPower[user];
    }

    // Function to get the list of users who received RT
    function getUsers() external view returns (address[] memory) {
        return _users;
    }
}

contract PercentToken is IERC20, ERC20Burnable, Ownable {
    // Minting variables
    uint256 public constant MINTING_INTERVAL = 1 days;
    uint256 public constant MINTING_AMOUNT = 1; // Mint 1 PT per interval
    uint256 public mintingStartTime;
    uint256 public mintingEndTime;

    constructor(uint256 initialSupply, uint256 mintingDurationInDays) ERC20("PercentToken", "PT") {
        uint256 totalSupply = initialSupply * 10**uint256(decimals());
        _mint(msg.sender, totalSupply);

        mintingStartTime = block.timestamp;
        mintingEndTime = block.timestamp + mintingDurationInDays * 1 days;
        /*if (msg.sender == owner()) {
            transferOwnership(msg.sender); // Set the contract owner to msg.sender
        }*/
    }

    // Function to transfer PT to another address
    function transferPT(address recipient, uint256 amount) public {
        //require(recipient != address(0), "Invalid recipient address.");
        //require(balanceOf(msg.sender) >= amount, "Insufficient PT balance.");

        _transfer(msg.sender, recipient, amount); // Use the ERC20 _transfer function
    }

    function mintPT() external onlyOwner {
        //require(block.timestamp >= mintingStartTime, "Minting has not started yet.");
        //require(block.timestamp <= mintingEndTime, "Minting has ended.");

        uint256 currentTime = block.timestamp;
        uint256 timeSinceStart = currentTime - mintingStartTime;
        uint256 intervals = timeSinceStart / MINTING_INTERVAL;
        uint256 amountToMint = MINTING_AMOUNT * intervals;

        _mint(owner(), amountToMint);
    }
}

contract DAO {
    string public name = "DAO";
    address public admin;

    struct Proposal {
        uint256 id;
        address creator;
        string description;
        uint256 votes;
        bool executed;
    }

    struct User {
        bool isConfirmed;
        uint256 referralCount;
        uint256 dailyRightsToken;
    }

    Proposal[] public proposals;
    address[] public users;

    mapping(address => User) public userData;

    event ProposalCreated(uint256 indexed proposalId, address indexed creator, string description);
    event Voted(uint256 indexed proposalId, address indexed voter, uint256 votes);
    event ProposalExecuted(uint256 indexed proposalId);

    constructor() {
        admin = msg.sender;
    }

    function joinDAO(address[] memory referrals) external {
        //require(!userData[msg.sender].isConfirmed, "User is already confirmed.");
        //require(referrals.length >= 6, "You need at least 6 referrals to be confirmed.");

        userData[msg.sender].isConfirmed = true;
        userData[msg.sender].referralCount = referrals.length;
        userData[msg.sender].dailyRightsToken = 0;

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < referrals.length; i++) {
            if (!userData[referrals[i]].isConfirmed) {
                userData[referrals[i]].referralCount++;
            }
        }

        users.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function submitProposal(string memory description) external {
        //require(userData[msg.sender].isConfirmed, "User must be confirmed to submit a proposal.");

        uint256 proposalId = proposals.length;
        Proposal memory newProposal = Proposal(proposalId, msg.sender, description, 0, false);
        proposals.push(newProposal);

        emit ProposalCreated(proposalId, msg.sender, description);
    }

    function voteOnProposal(uint256 proposalId, uint256 votes) external {
        //require(userData[msg.sender].isConfirmed, "User must be confirmed to vote.");
        //require(proposalId < proposals.length, "Invalid proposal ID.");

        Proposal storage proposal = proposals[proposalId];
        //require(!proposal.executed, "Proposal has already been executed.");

        userData[msg.sender].dailyRightsToken += votes;
        proposal.votes += votes;

        emit Voted(proposalId, msg.sender, votes);
    }

    function executeProposal(uint256 proposalId) external {
        //require(msg.sender == admin, "Only the admin can execute proposals.");
        //require(proposalId < proposals.length, "Invalid proposal ID.");

        Proposal storage proposal = proposals[proposalId];
        //require(!proposal.executed, "Proposal has already been executed.");

        // Execute the proposal (implement your logic here)
        // Example: Transfer funds, update state variables, etc.

        proposal.executed = true;

        emit ProposalExecuted(proposalId);
    }
}
```

It is accompanied by a React frontend, with `App.js` shown here:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Web3 from 'web3'; // Import Web3 library
import RightsTokenABI from './RightsToken.json';

function App() {
  const [web3, setWeb3] = useState(null); // Initialize state for Web3 instance
  const [account, setAccount] = useState('');
  const [rtBalance, setRTBalance] = useState(0);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  const rightsTokenAddress = '0xb92b7D5241085f8921d5F7C0956D941AA120c79B';
  const rightsTokenABI = RightsTokenABI.abi;

  const connectWallet = async () => {
    if (window.ethereum) {
      try {
        await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
        setAccount(window.ethereum.selectedAddress);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    } else {
      setMessage('Please install MetaMask and connect to an Ethereum network.');
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Check if MetaMask is installed and accessible
    if (window.ethereum) {
      const web3Instance = new Web3(window.ethereum); // Initialize Web3 with MetaMask provider
      setWeb3(web3Instance); // Set the Web3 instance in state

      // Request user account access if not already granted
      window.ethereum
        .request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' })
        .then((accounts) => {
          setAccount(accounts[0]); // Set the connected Ethereum account
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    } else {
      setMessage('Please install MetaMask and connect to an Ethereum network.');
    }
  }, []);

  const getRTBalance = async () => {
    if (!account) {
      setMessage('Connect your wallet to get your RT balance.');
      return;
    }

    const rightsTokenContract = new web3.eth.Contract(rightsTokenABI, rightsTokenAddress);
    try {
      const balance = await rightsTokenContract.methods.rtBalanceOf(account).call();
      setRTBalance(balance);
      setMessage(`Your RT balance: ${balance}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      setMessage('Failed to fetch RT balance. Error: ' + error.message);
    }
  };

  const claimRT = async () => {
    if (!account) {
      setMessage('Connect your wallet to claim RT.');
      return;
    }

    const rightsTokenContract = new web3.eth.Contract(rightsTokenABI, rightsTokenAddress);
    try {
      await rightsTokenContract.methods.distributeRT().send({ from: account });
      setMessage('Successfully claimed RT.');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      setMessage('Failed to claim RT. Error: ' + error.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>RightsToken Faucet</h1>
      <p>Connect your wallet to claim RT and check your balance.</p>
      {account ? (
        <div>
          <p>Connected Account: {account}</p>
          <button onClick={getRTBalance}>Check RT Balance</button>
          <button onClick={claimRT}>Claim RT</button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={connectWallet}>Connect Wallet</button>
      )}
      <p>{message}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'd run the Solidity smart contract on its own in Remix beforehand, with no issue apparent at the time. I then transitioned to using `truffle` to compile the smart contract for the React frontend, and the compilation (through `truffle migrate --network development`) does not show any errors, at all. I then added the valid contract address to the `App.js` code, and ran the frontend.

The React app correctly displays the account address connected to the app (I am using a local Ganache network for tests), along with the "check RT balance" button and the "claim RT" button. The Check RT balance button returns a value of zero, as should be expected- but the claim RT button does not do its function correctly.

When I click the claim RT button, it brings up the Metamask box in the upper-right, but instead of giving a normal option to commit ETH in exchange for the RT, but it shows a box saying "We were not able to estimate gas. There might be an error in the contract and this transaction may fail." When I continue with the transaction, it returns the error:

```
Returned error: [ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{"value":{"code":-32603,"data":{"message":"VM Exception while processing transaction: revert","stack":"RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert\n at EIP1559FeeMarketTransaction.fillFromResult (/tmp/.mount_ganachSuTauZ/resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/1.js:2:12745)\n at Miner.<anonymous> (/tmp/.mount_ganachSuTauZ/resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/1.js:2:36703)\n at async Miner.<anonymous> (/tmp/.mount_ganachSuTauZ/resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/1.js:2:35116)\n at async Miner.mine (/tmp/.mount_ganachSuTauZ/resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/1.js:2:39680)\n at async Blockchain.mine (/tmp/.mount_ganachSuTauZ/resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/1.js:2:60063)\n at async Promise.all (index 0)\n at async TransactionPool.emit (/tmp/.mount_ganachSuTauZ/resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache/node_modules/emittery/index.js:303:3)","code":-32000,"name":"RuntimeError","data":{"hash":"0xcdda2c0da386cd190e2830466f591a62a74dc566bca012e05a7feafa8e87b79a","programCounter":313,"result":"0xcdda2c0da386cd190e2830466f591a62a74dc566bca012e05a7feafa8e87b79a","reason":null,"message":"revert"}}}}'
```

One thing that stands out to me is, above all, the fact that the "reason" option is equal to "null". I've looked extensively throughout the Internet, StackOverflow and Ethereum's Stack Exchange, and asked ChatGPT for an answer (it'd given an answer for [a previous question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/155246/typeerror-abis-filter-is-not-a-function/155338) I asked), but I haven't even seen anything online matching the error I'm seeing. I saw that the "revert" notes may have to do with "require()" statements in the code, so I commented them all out temporarily, but the error never changed. The account I'm using, based on Ganache, has 99 ETH, and my gas limit is at what truffle has said is the highest possible- 6721975. Why is the error occurring, and how should it be fixed?

Comment: hey, you ever figure this one out?